# Difference between proc_lib:spawn and rpc:call in erlang

Tags: erlang

Can you please suggest me which one is the best? In my application I need to make sure that we achieve the highest throughput.

Comment: If you have multiple tasks that can be executed in parallel then `proc_lib:spawn` can be used to start all those tasks. `rpc:call` does each call sequentially. However, spawning a new process costs more than doing a simple function call. However again, `rpc:call` can also be used to call remote functions on other nodes over the network, which is not something `proc_lib:spawn` can provide. Summing up, you can't compare those functions because their purpose is different and which one to use depends on your problem at hand. Describe the problem in more detail and we will be able to help better.

Comment: I have a gen server running and I want to spawn a fsm one of the machines in a cluster (based on the key) to handle my request. I have 2 options. proc_lib:spawn_link(Node, riak_kv_put_fsm, start_link, [{raw, ReqId, Sender}, RObj, Options]),    or  rpc:call(Node, riak_kv_put_fsm, start_link,[{raw, ReqId, Sender}, RObj, Options]).  Both these methods can be used to execute remote functions in other nodes. I want to know which one performs the best. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation for both, it pretty much answers your question.

1. [proc_lib:spawn_link/4](http://erlang.org/doc/man/proc_lib.html#spawn_link-4)

It spawns a new process on the remote node and returns `pid()` of the process. It also links the local process with the just spawned remote process. The new process will then call `riak_kv_put_fsm:start_link/3` asynchronously, i.e. the code on the local node continues its execution and doesn't wait for the result of the call to `riak_kv_put_fsm:start_link/3` on the remote node. However, if something goes wrong the remote process will crash - and because those two processes are linked, the local process will receive an `'EXIT'` message from the process spawned on the remote node. See the [Error Handling](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#id86927) manual for more information about handling the `'EXIT'` messages.

If everything goes OK, the execution of the process started with `spawn_link` will eventually end. However, whatever was the result of the call to `riak_kv_put_fsm:start_link/3` will also be lost when the process stops executing. You need to have a way for the remote node to notify the local node that the call to `riak_kv_put_fsm:start_link/3` has been successful and it's now ready to accept calls from the local or other nodes.

2. [rpc:call/4](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html#call-4)

It handles the call synchronously, i.e. the local process makes the call and waits until it receives a response from the remote node. If something goes wrong during the call the function will return an error. It won't crash the process until there is an error in the remote function that isn't handled properly.

Summing up, the asynchronous call with `proc_lib:spawn_link/4` will be a bit slower on the remote node (because it spawns an additional process and creates the link), but it will be faster on the local node (because it doesn't need to wait for the result of the call and can continue executing). Also the synchronous call seems to be easier to comprehend, test and implement. The decision is yours.

Answer (score 0):

Amirax pointed out the major differences. Keep in mind you could also be using [rpc:async_call/4](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rpc.html#async_call-4) and fetch the result later.

Ultimately: Build and measure, improve and measure again.